# bash regex patch match

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I have a path such as thus ..

```
/Users/me/bla/dev/trunk/source/java/com/mecorp/sub/misc/filename.java
```

I'd like to be able to use bash to create the package structure in another dir somewhere e.g.

```
com/mecorp/sub/misc/
```

I tried the following but it wont work .. I was able to get a match if I change my regex to .* so that implies my bash is ok - There must be something wrong with the way im quoting the regex or maybe the regex its self. I do see working here ..

http://regexr.com?3439m

So im confused ?

```
regex="(?<=/java)(.*)(?=/)"


 [[ $fullfile =~ $regex ]]
 echo "pkg name " ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT - I'm using OSX so it doesn't have all those nice spiffy GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

using `GNU` [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ echo '/Users/me/bla/dev/trunk/source/java/com/mecorp/sub/misc/filename.java' | 
    grep -oP 'java/\K.*/'
com/mecorp/sub/misc/
```

See http://regexr.com?3439p

Or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
x="/Users/me/bla/dev/trunk/source/java/com/mecorp/sub/misc/filename.java"
[[ $x =~ java/(.*/) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
echo "$x" | awk -F/ '{print gensub(".*/java/(.*/).*", "\\1", $0)}'
```

Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
echo "$x" | sed -e 's@.*/java/\(.*/\).*@\1@'
```

Comment: Im running OSX and im not having any luck with the grep args for Answer 1. Answer 2 looks better but it seems to contain the java/ dir in the match. However I do appreciate your help @sputnkick :) !

Comment: excellent the sed does the business for me. The Awk didn't seem to find the gensub. I'll investigate sometime just for curiosity but you have me set with the sed. Merci beaucoup monsieur !

Answer (score 0):

If you try to extract the path after `/java/` you can do it with this:

```
path=/Users/me/bla/dev/trunk/source/java/com/mecorp/sub/misc/filename.java
package=`echo $path | sed -r 's,^.*/java/(.*/).*$,\1,'`
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment doesn't look as if my version of sed supports the -r option. (Mac OSX)